# ¿Como obtener el tab principal de un explorador?

Tags: c#

Hola he cambiado esta pregunta porque si se pudiera resolver la anterior daria el mismo resultado y he especificado mas la pregunta, este es el caso, estoy haciendo un lector de URL's de los exploradores web usando AutomationUI

```
try
        {
            AutomationElement Elemento = AutomationElement.FocusedElement;
            AutomationElement elm1 = Elemento.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));
            return ((ValuePattern)elm1.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

El problema es que este metodo obtiene la URL desde el MainWindowsHandle(Ventana) por lo cual si yo cambio rapido de tab el URL cambiara y me retornara la URL de la nueva tab y lo que necesito es que me retorne la vieja URL y la nueva, se me ocurrio hacer que cada tab la tome como un Elemento independiente del MainWindowsHandle y con ello poder sacar las URL individualmente, pero no se como se pueda hacer esto ¿Como puedo hacer que cada tab sea independiente y no cambie junto con el MainWindowHandle?

Comment: Deberias hacer tu propia clase, que herede de esta, implemente ICloneable, y sobreescribir el metodo clon...

Comment: @gbianchi ya lo intente pero la clase AutomationElement es sealed, no puedo heredar de ella